# Add many quotation in sed instruction

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have to update line with value containg many quotation  characters

```
sed -i 's/.*sonar.links.issue.*/property "sonar.links.issue", "http://jra.url"'
```

I get error there. What should i do to do it correctly?

Comment: your replacement string has slashes in it, and you're not terminating your sed command with a slash either...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -i 's@.*sonar.links.issue.*@property "sonar.links.issue", "http://jra.url"@' file
```

IHTH

Comment: @Rico, what part of the command don't you understand? Did you read/understand the comments to the Q and chab42's answer/comment? Have you worked thru the [sed tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) ? Good luck.

Comment: This showed up on the low-quality answer queue. So trying to see if we can provide more info on the answer.

Comment: @rico : If you have the power, I would recommend deleting this whole Q/A, as the O.P. never bothered to to reply. AND this sort of `sed` question gets asked every month. If the O.P. had asked for clarification,  I would have spent my time on it, but not now :-/

Comment: I don't have privileges to delete Q/As.  Feel free to vote to close or flag the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement string contains slashes "http://", so you shouldn't use / as the delimiter for this sed command, use @ as shellter proposes.
To complete its answer, I would add the "g" flag, at the end of the sed expression, to ensure the subsitution is made on the whole line, and not only on the first match with ".*sonar.links.issue.*".

`sed -i 's@.*sonar.links.issue.*@property "sonar.links.issue", "http://jra.url"@g' file`